# How to pass the video id in main page to another page like youtube?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, youtube, php-7

This is what in the main_page.html:

`<img src="..." onclick="openVideoPlayer('j2umt3WZU8Q')" >`

After clicked this image, the hidden form will be filled and use GET to video.php

```
 <!-- hidden form -->
    <form id="openVideoPlayerForm" action="player.php" method="get">
        <input id="form-video-id" tpye="text" name="videoID" value="" hidden />
    </form>
```

In video.php, I first make GET data into JSON and call initPage() -> js function to assign the video id attribute in youtube embed.

$video = $_GET['videoID'];

`function initPage(){
  var videoID = <?php echo json_encode($videoID) ?>;
  var videoPath = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoID + 'rel=0&amp;showinfo=0';
  $('#video-player').attr('src' , videoPath);
}`

The question is

1.

this is not work if I use php variable into js function (It is because I am using php 7.1 ?)

`var videoID = <?php echo json_encode($videoID) ?>;`

2.

I used this method to implement this "clone youtube" is it a best way?

Should I use ajax to implement this function?

If yes how to do.

[image for description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIxE4.png)

Comment: Open your console, it says "syntax error". `videoID + ?'rel=0&amp;showinfo=0'` should be `videoID + '?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0'` (Question mark INSIDE the quotes)

Comment: @JeremyThille This is my typing mistake  [edited now ] , this is not problem in my original code 

Answer (score 0):

Make VideoID a string, add quotes. This is currently invalid :

```
var videoID = <?php echo json_encode($videoID) ?>;
```

because it yields :

```
var videoID = X3pTXG9a1oQ; // Error : X3pTXG9a1oQ is not defined
```

Here again, open your console, it will tell you what's wrong.

You have to add quotes :

```
var videoID = "<?php echo json_encode($videoID) ?>";
```

which will yield :

```
var videoID = "X3pTXG9a1oQ"; // Valid
```

Comment: Then the php will not work
if I 
alert(videoID);
It will show : 
<?php echo json_encode($videoID) ?>;

Which means js will think that it is a long string

Comment: What? No, the PHP code will be interpreted. You can't see it client-side. It's rendered on the server, then sent to the client.

Comment: I mean 
if I implement your code
var videoID = "<?php echo json_encode($videoID) ?>";
and 
alert(videoID);
the browser will show me same as " <?php echo json_encode($videoID) ?>" not "X3pTXG9a1oQ"

Comment: Well then, there's something wrong. Your PHP code is not being interpreted on the server. You should not be able to see any PHP in the rendered HTML.

Comment: is your web page a *.php or *.html? For the php code to work, you need to have a php page.

Comment: @Tempus my page is .php

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and basic layout of what you should have

```
<?php
$video = $_GET['videoID'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
function initPage(){
  var videoID = ''+<?php echo $video ?>+'';
  var videoPath = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoID + 'rel=0&amp;showinfo=0';
  $('#video-player').attr('src' , videoPath);
}
</script> 

..... your other content and code.....

</body>
</html>
```